# How to get the basic HTTP authentication data in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-authentication

Where do I find the basic HTTP authentication credentials (username and password) in the incoming request to my server?

Is it somewhere in the `Request` object, or is there some other way to get them?

Running: IIS 7 - ASP.NET - .NET Framework 4 -  C#

Answer (score 3):

[Basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) details will be in the Request.Headers, with the key: "Authorization"

It's a base64 encoded string, which you'll need to decode. Check out [this post](http://cacheandquery.com/blog/2011/03/customizing-asp-net-mvc-basic-authentication/), there's a code sample in there that demonstrates picking that header apart.